# My development WordPress instance's admin page redirect's to Production admin page?

Tags: wordpress, development-environment

I have a development and production instance of WordPress in the same network. They both have different IP address. Development (10.10.132.211) and Production (10.10.132.209).

When I try to go to the development instances admin page, it goes to the Production instances admin page. Both of them have DNS entries.

http://development/wp-admin/ resolves to http://production/wp-admin/

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

check wp_option table for your instance's admin page redirect's to Production admin page issue
i suggest you check wp_option under column name : option_name and option_value
also check option values have proper site url or not

Comment: Thanks Anup. I need to test this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `site_url` and `home_url` in `wp_options` table.

Not to mention, `wp_` prefix can be replaced based on your table prefix from `wp-config.php`

Comment: Thanks! I need to check this